# Percorrer elementos e executar mesma função para cada um deles

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Estou fazendo uma galeria aonde as terá um botão de próximo e anterior. Ao clicar em um desses dois botões, executará a função que cabe a cada um deles executar. Existirá mais de uma galeria na mesma página. Irei renomear o ID da `<div>` por exemplo **galeria_1**, **galeria_2**, **galeria_3**. Mas no código `jquery` que tenho abaixo, queria se o usuário clicar no **proximo_2** então ele passar para o próximo a **galeria_2** conforme o código do plugin abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var owl = $("#galeria");

      owl.owlCarousel({
          items : 5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
          pagination: false,
          itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
          itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
          itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
          itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
      });

        $(".proximo").click(function(){
            owl.trigger('owl.next');
          });

          $(".anterior").click(function(){
            owl.trigger('owl.prev');
          });
});
```

Quero que esse mesmo script seja executado para todas as galeria que tenho, mas que a ação execute de acordo com o botão **proximo_x** ou **anterior_y**

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer algo assim:

```
var owl = $("#galeria1, #galeria2, galeia3");

$("#galeria1 .proximo").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.next'); });

$("#galeria1 .anterior").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.prev'); });

$("#galeria2 .proximo").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.next'); });

$("#galeria2 .anterior").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.prev'); });

$("#galeria3 .proximo").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.next'); });

$("#galeria3 .anterior").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.prev'); });
```

Se não der certo, eu acredito que você vai ter que multiplicar o script que você está usando de acordo com a quantidade galerias que vai ter.

Comment: Não daria para fazer essa sugestão de maneira mais económica? Está pouco DRY...

Comment: Poderia até tentar fazer algo como $(#galeria1, #galeria2, #galeria3 .proximo"), mas ai eu não sei como seria a interação entre o botão e os sliders, se de repente todos eles seriam movimentados de uma única vez ou algo assim.